# Descomponer un número en factores primos

Tags: javascript

tengo una consulta estoy pasando por un test un ejercicio el cual ya realize pero no encuentro el falloo me devuelve una array vacia y quiero que me devuelva los numeros primos del numero q estoy calculando, me pasan el numero primo como argumento para una funcion e hice un array con los primos necesarios para que pase el test y me voy parando segun el indice en cada uno de los elementos de un array y los voy analizando si se cumple la condicion. cual seria el fallo

```js
function factorear(num) {
  // Factorear el número recibido como parámetro y devolver en un array
  // los factores por los cuales se va dividiendo a dicho número (De menor a mayor)
  // Ej: factorear(180) --> [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5] Ya que 1x2x2x3x3x5 = 180 y son todos números primos
  // Tu código:
  var numsPrims = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]
  var arr = []
  var acc = num
  for (let i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
    while (acc % numsPrims[i] === 0) {
      arr.push(numsPrims[i])
      acc = acc / numsPrims[i]
    }
    if(i === 0) {
      arr.unshift(1)
    }
  }
  return arr
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En el bucle no recorres el array de numeros primos, pone num.length como límite y num no son los primos es el argumento que quieres descomponer en factores primos

```
function factorear(num) {
  var numsPrims = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]
  var arr = [1]
  var acc = num
  for (let i = 0; i < numsPrims.length; i++) {
    while (acc % numsPrims[i] === 0) {
      arr.push(numsPrims[i])
      acc = acc / numsPrims[i]
    }

  }
  return arr
}
console.log(factorear(9));
```

Comment: gracias bro, lo termine me habia equivocado en el .length, me pasan numero por argumento por eso no andaba eso era todo :D te agradezco mucho